2018: a year in moderation
It's New Year's Day in Stack Exchange land...
A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
-- A Theory of Moderation

While there certainly are Moderators here, a significant amount of the moderation is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.
As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Reverse Engineering breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  2          8
Users contacted                                   3          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue            64        236
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               12         70
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         12        130
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                9        119
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue               233        801
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue              205      1,021
Tags merged                                       1          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             0          6
Tag synonyms created                              6          0
Revisions redacted                                4          0
Questions reopened                               16          0
Questions protected                               0          5
Questions migrated                                3          0
Questions flagged⁴                                5        151
Questions closed                                150        200
Question flags handled⁴                         125         31
Posts unlocked                                    0          2
Posts undeleted                                   2         25
Posts locked                                      0          6
Posts deleted⁵                                  137        569
Posts bumped                                      0        620
Comments undeleted                                3          0
Comments flagged                                 52        173
Comments deleted⁶                               189        742
Comment flags handled                           106        119
Answers flagged                                   6        258
Answer flags handled                            229         35

Footnotes
¹ "Community" here refers both to the membership of Reverse Engineering without diamonds next to their names, and to the automated systems otherwise known as user #-1.
² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.
³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.
⁴ Includes close flags (but not close or reopen votes).
⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.
⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).
Wishing you all a happy new year...

And a happy new year to you as well. I noticed this summary first on devops.SE and headed over here to see whether we had our own summary. And sure enough we do. Are the scripts used to generate this information accessible anywhere?
